# Pagination between images (active/inactive)

Tags: images, pagination, gallery

I would like to add a check on the following piece of code that shows the arrows next/prev only if the next/prev image exists:

```
<div class="gallery-image"> 
    <p class="attachment">  
        <img src="<?php echo $att_image[0];?>" 
            width="<?php echo $att_image[1];?>" 
            height="<?php echo $att_image[2];?>"  
            class="attachment-medium" 
            alt="<?php $post->post_excerpt; ?>" />

        <span class="nav arrow previous">
            <?php previous_image_link(false); ?>
        </span>

        <span class="nav arrow next">
            <?php next_image_link(false); ?>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is an example of [last image of a gallery](http://www.fabiosirna.com/blog/2012/05/baciami-stupida/baciami-stupida-006/) so the next arrow shouldn't appears.

If you have any suggestions, please show me the right way to implement this behaviour :)

Thanks in advance,

Fabio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `previous_image_link()` only prints something if the there is a previous image. Similarly for `next_image_link()`.

The problem is that you're styling the containing `span` element - which always exists. Instead you should style the `a` tag inside the `span` (which only appears when there *is* a next/previous image).

Alternatively, digging into the source, both `previous_image_link` and `next_image_link` call `adjacent_image_link` ([see source](http://queryposts.com/function/adjacent_image_link/)). As noted above this prints the link *only* if the next/previous image exists. You can create your own function which, instead of printing the link - just returns true/false. **However, it would still preferable to use the solution outlined above.**

```
/**
 * Similar to adjacent_image_link().
 * Returns true/false if the adjacent image exists.
 * @param $prev (bool) true - look for previous image, false -look for next.
 */
function wpse57904_has_adjacent_image_link($prev = true) {
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($post);
    $attachments = array_values(get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->post_parent, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') ));

    foreach ( $attachments as $k => $attachment )
        if ( $attachment->ID == $post->ID )
            break;

    $k = $prev ? $k - 1 : $k + 1;

    return isset($attachments[$k]);
}
```